# Machine Learning - Decision Tree - Predicion Score

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

I have two binary classifiers one for Sports and the other for Entertainment. I am using decision trees for the binary classifier. If both classifiers predict true, i.e. the document is both Sports and Entertainment, is there a way to determine which has a better score? 
Basically, I would like to know how I can come up with a score for each of my predictions.
Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of measures: recall, F-score, accuracy,... Furthermore you need a testbench...

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "better score" ?

If you want to evaluate each predictor, you can use the measures already mentioned.

If by stating "is there a way to determine which has a better score" you mean "how can I determine If the document is more relevant to a sports document than to an entertainment document", then the decision tree approach you are using is not the way to go. You should follow the TF - IDF and cosine similarity approach, in order to determine the similarity of documents.

The following answer might be really useful:

[Learning to tag sentences with keywords based on examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442314/learning-to-tag-sentences-with-keywords-based-on-examples)